# How to say in german: "it would keep me from having to...."

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german

For example, suppose I wanted to say, "It would keep me from having to rewrite this."

Could I say, "Es würde mich davor bewahren, es umschreiben zu müssen." ?

Does bewahren work here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Es würde mich davor bewahren, es umschreiben zu müssen.

is correct. However, this is already high-brow German, and only used in very educated speech. Though you could make it top-notch by using *bewahrte* instead of *würde bewahren*.

In colloquial German, one would say and write

> Ich müsste es (dann) nicht umschreiben.

Answer (score 5):

The answer posted by [Janka](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/23885/janka) is definitively the correct one. Nevertheless, I want to point out, that

> Es würde mir ersparen, es umschreiben zu müssen.

is also a possible translation. I would use it especially when I am not feeling comfortable with the rewriting. So, the feelings connecting to rewriting are a little bit more negative with *ersparen* in comparison to the use of *bewahren*.

Answer (score 0):

Here some more forms to express this **in colloquial language** (meaning: grammatically not always quite kosher, but very typical for oral communication):

> Dann müsste ich's nicht umschreiben. [Oh, that was actually Janka's solution]
>
> Das [er]spart mir, dass ich's umschreiben muss.
>
> Das erspart mir das Umschreiben.
>
> Dann kann ich mir das Umschreiben sparen.

However, for colloquial language "umschreiben" itself is probably a little bit too high-tone. More hits in an everyday language sample would probably give:

> Dann müsst' ich's nicht nochmal[s] ändern.